# Scala pattern matching with async or future

Tags: scala, concurrency

Example code snippet :

```
def evalExpr(e: Expr): Int = e match {
  case Num(n) => n
  case Sum(l, r) => evalExpr(l) + evalExpr(r)
  case Prod(l, r) => evalExpr(l) * evalExpr(r)
}
```

What would be the best way to implement pattern matching where `evalExpr` runs asynchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can Wrap them in Scala's Futures :

```
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  trait Expr
  case class Num(n:Int) extends Expr
  case class Sum(n:Expr,m:Expr) extends Expr
  case class Prod(n:Expr,m:Expr) extends Expr

  def evalExpr(e: Expr): Future[Int] = e match {
    case Num(n) => Future(n)
    case Sum(l, r) =>
    val exp1 = evalExpr(l)
    val exp2 = evalExpr(r)
      for{
        i<-exp1
        j<-exp2
      } yield i + j

    case Prod(l, r) =>  
     val exp1 = evalExpr(l)
     val exp2 = evalExpr(r)
     for{
        i<-exp1
        j<-exp2
      } yield i + j
  }

evalExpr(Prod(Sum(Num(1),Prod(Num(3),Num(2))),Num(2))).map(println)


scala> evalExpr(Prod(Sum(Num(1),Prod(Num(3),Num(2))),Num(2))).map(println)
8 // As you can see output of the calculation is asynchronously printed. 
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@65039982
```

Comment: This won't really be fully parallel for the same reason as in jubis' answer.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I have edited my ans now , it will be parallel.

Answer (score 1):

If the `evalExpr(Expr)` would return `Future[Int]` you would write for instance `Prod(l, r)` like this:

```
case Prod(l, r) => {
  val eval1 = evalExpr(l)
  val eval2 = evalExpr(r)
  for {
    left <- eval1
    right <- eval2
  } yield left*right
}
```

This would combine the two futures - left and right - together and return new future.

Using futures also the `case Num(n)` should be `=> Future(n)`.

Comment: This won't work really in parallel because this for comprehension is equivalent to this chain of methods: `evalExpr(l).flatMap(left => evalExpr(r).map(right => left*right))` and this means that `evalExpr(r)` will only be run after `evalExpr(l)` is completed, which is no different from the regular sequential operations.

Comment: Very good point. @curious already provided the correct answer but I'll make the change too.